# Global sections on Projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is a follow up to the question and solution given here
[Global sections of the projective space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036404/global-sections-of-the-projective-space).

I understand that the SES tells us $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1})$ must be $\mathbb{C}$. But, when studying Riemann surfaces the field of functions one associates with the projective line is the field of fractions $\mathbb{C}(t)$. Why should I not expect to get this field, $\mathbb{C}(t)$, as global sections when studying varieties/schemes?

Moreover more general Riemann surfaces are given by finite extensions of $\mathbb{C}(t)$; what happens with varieties? Do they still have global sections isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$?

Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps I have confused _global sections_ and _function field_ ...

Comment: Yes you have. All Riemann surfaces will have $\mathcal O (V) = \mathbb C$. The finite extensions of $\mathbb C (t)$, as function fields, correspond to the bi rational equivalence classes of riemann surfaces